# Gdown is giving Permission error for particular file,although it is opening up fine manually

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am not able to download file using gdown package.It is giving permission error.
But when i am opening it manually.It is giving no such error and opening up fine.
Here is the code i am using and link

```
import gdown
url='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B1lRQVLFjBRNR3Jqam1menVtZnc'
output='letter.pdf'
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)
```

Error is 
Permission denied: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B1lRQVLFjBRNR3Jqam1menVtZnc
Maybe you need to change permission over 'Anyone with the link'?

Comment: This seems like a problem with the permissions of the file. Take into account that `gdown` need to be able to see the file as you are not introducing any permissions the link must be completely public. If you want you can file a bug in the [official `gdown` library](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're working with big files (in my case was a >1gb file), you can solve by copying the url from 'Download anyway' button in Google Drive.

Comment: I am using gdown.cli. `python3 -m gdown.cli 0B1lRQVLFjBRNR3Jqam1menVtZnc` gives me the error, but when I use the URL with "confirm=t" it works: `python3 -m gdown.cli "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B1lRQVLFjBRNR3Jqam1menVtZnc&confirm=t"`

Comment: simply calling 
`gdown "<drive-id>&confirm=t"` 
works. and yes problem is large file.

Comment: Thanks @MelihDal for your answer ! This work like a charm for big file on Google Drive ! Thanks !

Answer (score 69):

In my case, I ran the following command and try using `gdown`, and problem was solved:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir gdown
```

If you are using google-colab, try:

```
!pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir gdown
```

then:
`!gdown --id [id of your file]`

Comment: This solution helped me, some files randomly throw the permission denied error and it gets solve by upgrading gdown

Comment: upgrading `gdown` made it work! I was on version `4.2.2` but now on `4.5.1`

Answer (score 14):

instead of

`gdown <drive-id>`

type

`gdown "<drive-id>&confirm=t"`

for large files.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the older versions of gdown are causing issues.
The following version worked for me.

```
pip install gdown==4.5.1
```

or

```
pip install gdown==4.6.0
```

Comment: working as of 13/01/2024

Comment: this doesn't work for me.  However, 4.6.0 does work!

Comment: @bsabiston thanks! that worked for me as well. Was trying to figure out what might be causing the issue.

Comment: My file size was around 10 GB and After "pip install==4.6.0", it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's March 2024, and I still face the same issues too. I found the following code works well for me in Colab.

Install gdown

```
!pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir gdown
```

And then download the file with Python

```
import gdown
file_id = "your drive file ID"
output_file = "model.zip"
gdown.download(f"https://drive.google.com/uc?id={file_id}", output_file)
```

Or gdown command

```
!gdown "your_file_id_here&confirm=t"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your downloadable zip folder and make it *"Anyone with the link"* and change *"Viewer*" to *"Editor"*.

Finally use:

```
!gdown --id 'id of the file'
```

Comment: This would not help if the file is coming from someone else and all we have is the google drive link without any permission to make aforementioned changes

Answer (score 1):

`pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir gdown`
didn't work for me.

You can try pre-released version of this :
`pip install -U --no-cache-dir gdown --pre`
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with gdown(version 4.7.1) and tried many solutions as given in this page but nothing worked.

**I have downgraded my gdown to 4.6.0** and it worked.

Comment: Me too. It just happened yesterday. Before, it worked fine with 4.7.1. Now I have to downgrade to 4.6.0. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that instead of using the full URL, you can just use the google drive id, at least that works for me.

in your case, this would work:

```
import gdown
url='0B1lRQVLFjBRNR3Jqam1menVtZnc'
output='letter.pdf'
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time, but I have not found it, but it turned out that the solution is very simple.
Just use_cookies=True
In this way:
gdown.download(url=url, output=output, quiet=True,
fuzzy=True, use_cookies=True)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the folder to which you are downloading to, in my case I was downloading into the html folder which was given me permission errors.